# Can't change Voice and Culture

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I may be doing something wrong but i cant change the Voice, VoiceGender and Culture...

This is how my code looks like right now: https://pastebin.com/XYu8FCcn

This is the result:

[image]

I have tried things like...

```
_SS.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male, VoiceAge.Adult, 0, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
_SS.SelectVoice("Microsoft Mike");
```

but the result is always the same... like i am stuck on `Microsoft Mary` Voice speaking pt-BR (i am from brazil but i want my TTS to speak en-US)

I dont know if its a System Config that i need to add/change, or if i am just doing something wrong... any ideas?

---

If this question is Duplicated, please consider sending me the question that you think may solve my problem!

Comment: Do you have the voices you are trying to select installed on your computer? Use `GetInstalledVoices()` to check. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.selectvoice(v=office.14).aspx#Anchor_2) to usage.

Comment: My program shows the output of `GetInstalledVoices()` on the botton right corner, just like on the picture